# Define Tabhost/TabWidget + content within the xml file without any code - is that possible?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

Is it possible to define a tab layout only within the layout xml file? Everytime I find a tabhost tutorial it only works with some additional java code.

Here is my test.xml which don't display any tabs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    <TextView android:text="@string/app_name" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"></TextView>
    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TabWidget android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@android:id/tabs">
        </TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tab1">
                <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TAB 1"/>
            </LinearLayout>   
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tab2">
                <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TAB 2"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible, as [TabSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html) is the holder class which represents each tab in TabHost.
and there is no TabSpec xml equivalent tags specified to be put in xml layout.

Even through code, for a TabSpec, an indicator and content both have to be specified. Otherwise it will throw either

```
IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content
```

or

```
IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab indicator.
```