# android tabs repeated content

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs

I've set up a tab host and defined 5 tabs both in the xml file and the corresponding java class file. I added some fields for tab 1 and a test field for tab 2 but all I see in each tab is the repeated content from tab 1. Has anyone come across this before? code is pasted below.

Thanks

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inspection);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Part1");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabPart1);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("1");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabHost.newTabSpec("Part2");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabPart2);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("2");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabHost.newTabSpec("Part3");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabPart3);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("3");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabHost.newTabSpec("Part4");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabPart4);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("4");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabHost.newTabSpec("Part5");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabPart5);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("5");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
```

and the xml code:

```
 <TabHost
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabPart1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Id"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:hint="Global Unique ID" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/jobNum"
                    android:hint="Job Number"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Required?"
                    android:id="@+id/req"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/material"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:hint="Material" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/shape"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:hint="Shape" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/size"
                    android:hint="Size (mm)"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:id="@+id/LvlCollectGp">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Collect Now?"
                            android:id="@+id/collectNow"
                            android:hint="Collect Now?" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Collect Later?"
                            android:id="@+id/collectLtr" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/lvl"
                    android:hint="Level (m)"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabPart2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/test"
                    android:hint="Test" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabPart3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabPart4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabPart5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996474/define-tabhost-tabwidget-content-within-the-xml-file-without-any-code-is-tha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inspection);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Part1");
    tabSpec1.setContent(R.id.tabPart1);
    tabSpec1.setIndicator("1");
    tabHost1.addTab(tabSpec1);

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Part2");
    tabSpec2.setContent(R.id.tabPart2);
    tabSpec2.setIndicator("2");
    tabHost2.addTab(tabSpec2);

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Part3");
    tabSpec3.setContent(R.id.tabPart3);
    tabSpec3.setIndicator("3");
    tabHost3.addTab(tabSpec3);

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec4 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Part4");
    tabSpec4.setContent(R.id.tabPart4);
    tabSpec4.setIndicator("4");
    tabHost4.addTab(tabSpec4);

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec5 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Part5");
    tabSpec5.setContent(R.id.tabPart5);
    tabSpec5.setIndicator("5");
    tabHost5.addTab(tabSpec5);
}
```